# How to recognise the current element on screen in ListView horizontal

Tags: react-native

As shown in attached screenshot. I want to highlight the marker according to the property tile on screen below. I am unable to identify the active (or current) element.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an NPM module for that, it should do the job:

[react-native-inviewport](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-inviewport)